# Access network share of guest on host

Tags: networking, windows-7, virtualbox, shared-folders, network-drive

I use an Ubuntu 12.04 host system with a Windows 7 guest in VirtualBox.

The virtual Windows machine is member of a domain in which network drives are shared to it.

I prefer to do most of the work on the host system and use the Windows system for programs that do not run (in an acceptable way) on Ubuntu (yet) only. Therefore I need to access those folders shared to the Windows guest system on the host system.

Is there any sort of reverse shared folder (from guest to host)?

The original workaround of sharing the folder via a host-only-network and mounting it on the host system doesn't work because afaik it's impossible to share a drive mapped via network.

Any suggestions on how to solve this in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar situation here: there is a number of Windows network shares that my Windows guest system is accessing. My solution is just to mount the shares in the Ubuntu host via Samba, using the Nautilus URl `smb://.../...`. Usually, I then directly access them through `~/.gvfs/....` (or other mount point depending on your Ubuntu version).

If you cannot find the share by browsing the windows network, but know the fileserver and the share name, you can enter directly in the Nautilus' address bar (`Go -> Location` from the menu) the following URL:

```
smb://fileserver/sharename/
```

Alternatively, you can use the `mount` command like this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username,blah,blah //servername/sharename/ /mountpoint
```

or use an entry in your fstab.

Basically, if your Windows guest can access it, your Ubuntu host should be able to mount it as well.

In other words, instead of `Windows network -> Windows guest -> Ubuntu host` I mount `Windows network -> Windows guest` and `Windows network -> Ubuntu host` directly.

Comment: Accessing the network via `'Browse Network' -> 'Windows Network'` doesn't work. (**"Unable to mount location. Failed to retrieve share list from server."**)

Do you actually mount the drives via `mount <IP>:<path> <localpath>` or do you just enter the address somehow somewhere?

Comment: I edited the answer. Yes, you can use `mount` as well; personally, I find it too much of a hassle. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right. :) I tried it out today and it's working.